# Use Plugin Java API from Gradle build script

Tags: gradle

I am trying to install a jar in my maven repository with the plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
```

Following the doc I am trying it this way:

```
def installer = install.repositories.mavenInstaller

[installer]*.pom*.whenConfigured {pom ->
    println pom
    org.apache.maven.model.Exclusion exclusion = new org.apache.maven.model.Exclusion()
    exclusion.setArtifactId("*")
    exclusion.setGroupId("*")
    pom.dependencies.each { dep -> dep.addExclusion(exclusion) }
}
```

But it fails with:

```
unable to resolve class org.apache.maven.model.Exclusion
```

More generally, how do I know how go from the plugin's API to the Gradle DSL?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you look at the documentation for the plugin.

In this case, is there a reason you don't use the newer `maven-publish` plugin which might be easier to use than the old `maven` plugin?

Comment: How can I add those exclusions with maven-publish?

Comment: What do I do in the pom.withXml? How do I add an exclusion?

Comment: You can use the POM as DOM tree with `asElement()` or as Groovy Node tree with `asNode()` and then manipulate the tree freely to add exclusion nodes where you need them. Here you have the entry point, just follow the JavaDoc: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/XmlProvider.html